# mysqldump behavior and related InnoDB performance

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

I have the following mysqldump file . I have 3 questions:

**1.** Are the commands within `/* */` commented out or are they actually getting executed?

**2.** According to the official [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) it says:

> The mysqldump option --opt creates dump files that are fast to import
>   into an InnoDB table, even without wrapping them with the SET
>   autocommit and COMMIT statements. opt is enabled by default

But `mysqldump` file didn’t include `SET auto commit` and `COMMIT` statements, I’m wondering if those are implicit? Or do I need to add them.

**3.** Even when I set `unique_checks=0` and `foreign_key_checks=0`, if I have non-unique key, I should probably remove these keys prior to the bulk insert, and then re-add them afterwards, in order to gain performance, right?

```
-- Server version   5.6.10-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;



LOCK TABLES `xxx` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `xxx` DISABLE KEYS */;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **1.** Are the commands within /* */ commented out or are they actually
>   getting executed?

Yes, they are actually being executed, but only for versions of MySQL equal to or higher than the version number of `/*!40101` as shown in your example. As per [the MySQL manual on comment syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comments.html):

> If you add a version number after the “!” character, the syntax within
>   the comment is executed only if the MySQL version is greater than or
>   equal to the specified version number.

Then as far as `mysqldump` & InnoDB performance goes:

> **2.** But `mysqldump` file didn’t include `SET auto commit` and `COMMIT`
>   statements, I’m wondering if those are implicit? Or do I need to add
>   them.

As explained [in the official MySQL performance tips](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-tuning.html):

> When importing data into InnoDB, make sure that MySQL does not have
>   autocommit mode enabled because that requires a log flush to disk for
>   every insert. To disable autocommit during your import operation,
>   surround it with SET auto commit and COMMIT statements.

This is completely different from this:

> If you use the mysqldump option --opt, you get dump files that are
>   fast to import into an InnoDB table, even without wrapping them with
>   the `SET autocommit` and `COMMIT` statements.

It’s not actually disabling `SET auto commit` and `COMMIT` statements. It simply acts on the defaults of your InnoDB setup which means it is implicitly set.

> **3.** Even when I set `unique_checks=0` and `foreign_key_checks=0,` if I have non-unique key, I should probably remove these keys prior to the
>   bulk insert, and then re-add them afterwards, in order to gain
>   performance, right?

I am pretty confident that the act of exporting  via `mysqldump` and then importing again will automatically do house cleaning like this. Okay, dug around some more & it seems that “random” keys [can negatively impact InnoDB import performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819271/why-is-mysql-innodb-insert-so-slow#9819411). The clear advice from Paul Dixon’s answer (bold emphasis is mine), “Your ‘real’ key field could still be indexed, but for a bulk insert **you might be better off dropping and recreating that index in one hit after the insert in complete**.”

Comment: is there a way to remove the version constraint on the comment when doing mysqldump?

Comment: suppose I need to SET autocommit=0; and then execute from a mysqldump file, and then commit; can this be done without modifying mysqldump file in one/multiple commands in bash?