# Very Slow Eloquent Insert/Update Queries in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, performance, database-performance, database-tuning

I have a laravel application which must `insert/update` thousands of records per second in a for loop. my problem is that my Database `insert/update` rate is **100-150** writes per second . I have increased the amount of **RAM** dedicated to my database but got no luck.

[image]

is there any way to increase the write rate for **mysql** to thousands of records per second ?

> please provide me optimum configurations for performance tuning

and **PLEASE** do not down mark the question . my code is correct . Its not a code problem because I have no problem with **MONGODB** . but I have to use mysql .

My Storage Engine is `InnoDB`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-optimization.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819271/why-is-mysql-innodb-insert-so-slow https://serverfault.com/questions/118504/how-to-improve-mysql-insert-and-update-performance

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks . I will check these out

Comment: Batch processing is your friend.  Maybe do 10 to 100 inserts in a single statement?  `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` could work for updates unless better is needed.  NOTE: fewer transactions is also generally good if you're using transactions.

Comment: What makes you think it`s slow?Also you are comparing mongo with mysql which is apple to oranges.Show some sample data for inserts or better yet that loop you mentioned.

Comment: @Mihai It does 100's of operations and Ramin wants (or needs) 1000's of operations per second therefore, by definition, it's an order of magnitude "too slow".

Comment: @Mihai because its not even 1000 transactions/s on a 8 GB RAM core i5 CPU . it should not be like this in my opinion

Comment: I have read on a question of Stackoverflow that mysql is capable of thousands of transactions/s

Comment: @ebyrob I have tries transactions for my inserts & updates but no different results . It has to be some misconfiguration

Comment: @Ramin If you can isolate to mostly `insert` transactions and just modify the insert code to do 2 inserts every execute call that might give you an idea if batching might help.  Of course, you're right if it's tuning it'll be a lot more difficult for us to help from a generic standpoint.  Also you're 100% autocommit is off?

Comment: @ebyrob thanks for the help

Comment: Dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/176301/mysql-insert-update-is-so-slow

Answer (score 3):

Inserting rows one at a time, and autocommitting each statement, has two overheads.

Each *transaction* has overhead, probably more than one insert.  So inserting multiple rows in one transaction is the trick.  This requires a *code* change, not a *configuration* change.

Each `INSERT` *statement* has overhead.  One insert has about 90% over head and 10% actual insert.

The optimal is 100-1000 *rows* being inserted per *transaction*.

For rapid inserts:

- Best is `LOAD DATA` -- if you are starting with a .csv file.  If you must build the .csv file first, then it is debatable whether *that overhead* makes this  approach lose.
- Second best is multi-row `INSERT` statements:  `INSERT INTO t (a,b) VALUES (1,2), (2,3), (44,55), ...`.  I recommend 1000 per statement, and `COMMIT` each statement.  This is likely to get you past 1000 *rows* per second being inserted.

Another problem...  Since each index is updated as the row is inserted, you *may* run into trouble with thrashing I/O to achieve this task.  InnoDB automatically "delays" updates to non-unique secondary indexes (no need for `INSERT DELAYED`), but the work is eventually done.  (So RAM size and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` come into play.)

If the "thousands" of rows/second is a one time task, then you can stop reading here.  If you expect to do this continually 'forever', there are other issues to contend with.  See [*High speed ingestion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) .

Answer (score 2):

For insert, you might want to look into the [`INSERT DELAYED`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html) syntax. That will increase insert performance, but it won't help with update and the syntax will eventually be deprecated. [This post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33772/how-to-do-something-like-update-delayed-in-mysql) offers an alternative for updates, but it involves custom replication.

One way my company's succeeded in speeding up inserts is by writing the SQL to a file, and then doing using a MySQL [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) command, but I believe we found that required the server's command line to have the `mysql` application installed.

I've also found that inserting and updating in a batch is often faster. So if you're calling `INSERT` 2k times, you might be better off running 10 inserts of 200 rows each. This would decrease the lock requirements and decrease information/number of calls sent over the wire.

Comment: Thanks buddy . after a while I resolved this by using transactions and sending all data in one go to the database server

Comment: I will write it here later

Comment: `INSERT DELAYED` applies to MyISAM and not InnoDB.  `LOAD DATA` is an SQL statement, so if you can issue "raw" SQL, it should not need the `mysql` client.  However, the overhead of writing the file may wipe out most of `LOAD's` benefit.