# Slow mysql transactions in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am having issues with my rails 7 server with mysql 8 on several big tables that contain around 1 million records.
The tables contains less than ten fields, an index on the id and an index on user_id, pointing to the table users.
Around once a second, I update a row in those tables. Less frequently, I insert a row.
The row select/update take 0.2 ms according to rails, similar to the row insert. But the transaction commit for insert/update takes around a second.
I'm baffled at how that could be so slow. Also my server is experiencing a lot of I/O wait, but I don't think this it the cause of those slow transactions, but rather the effect.

Comment: Transaction commit log setting might be issue [https://stackoverflow.com/a/11818256/6519224](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11818256/6519224)

Comment: @DeepakD Thank you, I thought about it but don't really like the idea of possible data corruption. It may help but I feel like I shouldn't have to do that, why would an update take 1 second because of a transaction?

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Thank you @WilsonHauck, here is the information requested: https://justpaste.it/fvgig

Comment: Thanks for posting the data.  Does your MySQL server have any SSD or NVME data storage?  Analysis in process.  May take 48 hours before any Suggestions posted due to medical appointments.

Comment: @WilsonHauck thank you very much, no, no ssd or NVME.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_io_capacity=500  # from 200 to enable more IOPS
read_rnd_buffer_size=16384  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 6,970
read_buffer_size=524288  # from 128K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 29,861
net_buffer_length=98304  # from 16384 to reduce packet count in/out
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT  # from fsync is typically used with Linux/Ubun
```

More opportunities exist to improve performance.  Please view my profile.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It didn't seem to have improved performance unfortunately. I now suspect something went wrong during my ubuntu upgrade as it isn't loading the right kernel. I found out I could simply switch to a more performant server for the same price so I'll probably do that and that should fix any conf/hardware/install issue.

Comment: The BEST to you always.  Bigger/more performant server will be in your best interest.  When you need speed improvements let us know.  Configuration holds the keys.